# DeadlineExceededError: The API call taskqueue.BulkAdd() took too long to respond and was cancelled

Tags: google-app-engine

I started seeing this error more and more in my logs the past few days -- are there backend issues?

**Edit**:

Looks like [people](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11119) are seeing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this same error message this morning.  No changes to the code on my end, so it must be a GAE backend issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added some code to do an exponential backoff and keep trying -- some requests work perfectly, others will eventually go through after maybe 5-10 attempts. Very odd.

Comment: See my edit above if you're still having problems -- looks like other people may be seeing something similar.

Comment: I've randomly seen this (over a year after the OP). This is the cost of dealing with GAE's black box.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I had similar issue like `The API call stubby.Send() took too long to respond and was cancelled.`

Deploy again will make it work and it might be the issue of GAE or GCloud tool.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the API call exceeded the deadline of 5 seconds. As a quick solution you can catch an exception as per [1] and retry with exponential backoff. However, if you're seeing too many errors, try to reduce the number of tasks for bulk add.

[1] - https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors